# Google play error during apk upload

Tags: android, phonegap-build

I get this error while trying to upload an apk on google play:

> You uploaded a debuggable APK. For security reasons you need to
>   disable debugging before it can be published in Google Play.

I am using phonegap build (version 2.9)...I still uploaded an apk for the same app about 3 weeks ago without any issue. The solutions I found online has to do with the android manifest file which phonegap build doesn't have...

Comment: every application have a file called `AndroidManifest.xml` [Android doc](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/preparing.html)

Comment: Please do you know how I can get the AndroidManifest.xml of an android app built with phonegap build.....I have tried renaming the apk file to ".zip" I see d AndroidManifest.xml but when I open it, it doesnt contain xml, looks like d file has been corrupted or or something...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to edit the app with with apktool, made the change to the AndroidManifest.xml,  then re-sign with jarsigner and finally wrapped it up with zipalign....it uploads correctly now...I guess the problem was that phonegap build changed the way they build android apks

Answer (score 0):

I think in BuildConfiure.java make DEBUG = false;  while deploying .apk i think we should make it false

Answer (score 0):

Add

> android:debuggable="false"

into manifest.

And also back to the PhoneGap Build interface, clicked Settings, unchecked the "Enable Debugging" box and then recompiled.